# Wireguard VPN (client on router) - no RX connection - two routers

Tags: vpn, wireguard

Wireguard VPN client on router B (with OpenWrt) does not download RX data (tx works)

1. Internet is delivered to router A (TP-Link) - IP: 192.168.0.1
2. I have set up a Wireguard VPN server on Raspberry pi 4, connected via LAN to router A with IP: 192.168.0.100
3. I have router B (with OpenWrt system) with its own subnet 192.168.2.1, connected via LAN to router A under IP: 192.168.0.104

Configuration on router A (tp-link IP: 192.168.0.1):

1. I opened port 51820 to the IP address of the VPN server on Raspberry pi 4 (192.168.0.101)
2. I don't know if it's necessary, but I created a static route for router B with Destination IP: 192.168.2.0 and Gateway 192.168.0.104

Configuration on router B (OpenWrt 192.168.2.1):

1. I connected the Wireguard client and there is no internet
2. Firewall rules for VPN done in the same way as WAN, or if I configured another VPN operator - e.g. Surfshark or NordVpn - it works for them.
3. I did not open any ports or do a static route because it is a VPN client

Now the VPN client from the Raspberry server works on my computer or phone, but not on the B router - no RX data download.

- The identical configuration of firewalls and others on router B allows, for example, the NordVpn or Surfsark interface to work but not work with Raspberry.

Since everything else works everywhere, it may be influenced by the fact that all data travels over the same Internet connection. Maybe some endpoint in the PEER of the Wireguard client needs to be changed.

I have no idea how to get past this.

......................................
edit ......................................

Above I corrected the IP number due to the restart.

Below are screenshots of the whole thing

```
Here Wireguard Client:

[Interface]
PrivateKey = 2HxxxkI=
Address = 10.yyy.2/24
DNS = 9.9.9.9, 149.112.112.112

[Peer]
PublicKey = p7xxxTQ=
PresharedKey = ZExxx4o=
Endpoint = 84.yyy.100:51820
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0, ::0/0
```

Here my server VPN configuration (from PIVPN -debug in Raspberry Pi):

```
=============================================
::::        Installation settings        ::::
PLAT=Raspbian
OSCN=bullseye
USING_UFW=0
pivpnforceipv6route=1
IPv4dev=eth0
IPv4addr=192.168.0.101/24
IPv4gw=192.168.0.1
install_user=xxx
install_home=/home/xxx
VPN=wireguard
pivpnPORT=51820
pivpnDNS1=9.9.9.9
pivpnDNS2=149.112.112.112
pivpnHOST=REDACTED
INPUT_CHAIN_EDITED=0
FORWARD_CHAIN_EDITED=0
INPUT_CHAIN_EDITEDv6=
FORWARD_CHAIN_EDITEDv6=
pivpnPROTO=udp
pivpnMTU=1420
pivpnDEV=wg0
pivpnNET=10.yyy.0
subnetClass=24
pivpnenableipv6=0
ALLOWED_IPS="0.0.0.0/0, ::0/0"
UNATTUPG=1
INSTALLED_PACKAGES=(dnsutils grepcidr bsdmainutils iptables-persistent wireguard-tools qrencode unattended-upgrades)


=============================================
::::  Server configuration shown below   ::::
[Interface]
PrivateKey = server_priv
Address = 10.yyy.1/24
MTU = 1420
ListenPort = 51820
### begin testClient ###
[Peer]
PublicKey = testClient_pub
PresharedKey = testClient_psk
AllowedIPs = 10.yyy.2/32
### end testClient###

=============================================
::::  Client configuration shown below   ::::
[Interface]
PrivateKey = testClient
Address = 10.yyy.2/24
DNS = 9.9.9.9, 149.112.112.112

[Peer]
PublicKey = server_pub
PresharedKey = testClient_psk
Endpoint = REDACTED:51820
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0, ::0/0


=============================================
::::            Self check               ::::
:: [OK] IP forwarding is enabled
:: [OK] Iptables MASQUERADE rule set
:: [OK] WireGuard is running
:: [OK] WireGuard is enabled
(it will automatically start on reboot)
:: [OK] WireGuard is listening on port 51820/udp
=============================================
```

Here my network configuration from router B with OpenWrt:

```
config interface 'loopback'
        option device 'lo'
        option proto 'static'
        option ipaddr '127.xxx.1'
        option netmask '255.xxx.0'

config globals 'globals'
        option packet_steering '1'
        option ula_prefix 'fde8:xxx3::/48'

config device
        option name 'br-lan'
        option type 'bridge'
        list ports 'lan1'
        list ports 'lan2'
        list ports 'lan3'
        list ports 'lan4'

config interface 'lan'
        option device 'br-lan'
        option proto 'static'
        option netmask '255.255.255.0'
        option ip6assign '60'
        option ipaddr '192.168.2.1'

config interface 'wan'
        option device 'wan'
        option proto 'dhcp'

config interface 'wan6'
        option device 'wan'
        option proto 'dhcpv6'

config interface 'wg0'
        option proto 'wireguard'
        list dns '9.9.9.9'
        list dns '149.112.112.112'
        option auto '0'
        option private_key '2xxxkI='
        list addresses '10.yyy.2/24'

config wireguard_wg0
        option description 'something'
        option route_allowed_ips '1'
        option endpoint_port '51820'
        list allowed_ips '0.0.0.0/0'
        list allowed_ips '::0/0'
        option endpoint_host '84.xxx.100'
        option public_key 'p7xxxTQ='
```

Here screens from firewall router B OpenWrt:

[1 Router A - Forwarding and Static](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2Ejk.jpg)

[5a Router B - Firewall 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wz3lW.jpg)

[5b Router B - Firewall 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7z2m5.jpg)

[Diagram Network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NX7J4.jpg)

Comment: You should really at least share the current wg conf (at the very least, start with the client one). (With keys redacted, if you have concern and don't want to regen or whatever.) `Maybe some endpoint in the PEER of the Wireguard client needs to be changed.` We don't even know what you are using.

Comment: I do have a guess though. You are not using `192.168.0.50` as the endpoint on the B router conf (but the WAN IP of router A) which leads to NAT hairpin problem?

Comment: `static route for router B with Destination IP: 192.168.2.0 and Gateway 192.168.0.51` It's actually more ideal to have the route on the Pi. (But I suppose you don't need it anywhere since you probably don't have the NAT disabled on router B. Also because your WG client is on the router itself.)

Comment: Due to the reset of everything, I changed and corrected the IP subnet addresses to new ones and added screenshots, VPN client and server configuration.